# Common practise to shutdown camel consumer

Tags: apache-camel, kestrel

We start our `camel`(kestrel queue) consumers running inside a spring context from maven as `mvn camel:run`.

We used to kill this using `pkill -9 -f camel`. But now, we are moving more critical components into queue and cannot afford killing consumers mid way.

Camel has provision for graceful shutdown but the question is how do we stop consumers, will using a `pkill camel` kill it gracefully? What is the common practice to shutdown camel consumers?

Comment: Tried pkill camel, does not work.

Answer (score 0):

What about kill -3 to signal you want to kill the process? There is shutdown hook when using camel:run that may trigger and issues a graceful shutdown of Camel.

Comment: I tried this, but does not shutdown camel. I see the thread trace getting printed on screen when I try to shutdown using -3 signal. To confirm, I registered a JVM shutdown hook, but that too is not getting invoked on shutdown.